# Identify frequency components

Tags: fourier-analysis, frequency

I try to perform data analysis on wind power production.
Data consist in 17520 points, corresponding to the production averaged over 30 minutes over the 365 days of the year.

I somehow expect to see a periodic pattern, at least some day/night variations (1/2 day period). However, I don't see any frequency single out in the Fourier spectrum.

Am I doing something wrong or are data just flat noise ?

Data are (hopefully) available [here](http://pastebin.com/DJxHxZeD)

```
NbPt = Length[dataWind]
dt = 1/48;
time = dt*NbPt;
wgrid = RotateRight[1/(NbPt*dt)*Range[-(NbPt/2), NbPt/2 - 1], NbPt/2];
SF = Transpose[{wgrid, Abs[Fourier[dataWind]]}]
ListPlot[SF, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, All}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

and the result I get is the following 
[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a dominant mean value. You may find it useful to look here Http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558  for some information on how to set up your axis.

Comment: Yes in deed, substracting a mean tendency helped reading the data. Thanks.